# Zsh - how to enable backspace terminal beep sound

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, gnome, bell

How can I enable the bell sound in my kali linux terminal (zsh) when I backspace or hit tab for suggestions, notice that the beep works when I'm in a sub shell (eg. I accessed mysql CLI the backspace works fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In zsh, and in emacs mode, `backward-delete-char` is the widget bound to <kbd>Backspace</kbd> by default.

You can tell what a key is bound to using the `describe-key-briefly` widget. That widget is not bound to any key by default but you can run arbitrary zle widgets in emacs mode using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> (like in emacs) and enter the widget there (tab completion available).

So <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>desc<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd> will show:

```
"^?" is backward-delete-char
```

`^?` being a representation of the DEL character that most terminal emulators send upon <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

Or you can run:

```
$ bindkey '^?'
"^?" backward-delete-char
```

That `backward-delete-char` widget only beeps when given a negative numeric argument, like when entering <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd>, in which case it deletes 5 characters *forward* instead of backward (like in emacs) and if there aren't that many characters to delete, it beeps and deletes none (and moves the cursor to the end which is a deviation from emacs' behaviour)

If you want it to beep when invoked at the start of the line or with a numeric argument that is greater than the number of characters that there is to delete, you can redefine it as:

```
backward-delete-char() {
  local enough_chars=$(( CURSOR >= ${NUMERIC:-1} ))
  zle .$WIDGET && (( enough_chars ))
}
zle -N backward-delete-char
```

There should be beeping upon failed completions by default. If there isn't, maybe there's a `setopt nobeep`/`unsetopt beep`/`set +o beep`... in your `~/.zshrc` or `/etc/zsh/zshrc` or any file they source. You can check the state of that option with `echo $options[beep]`, and if you can't spot where that `set +o beep` is, you can always add a `set -o beep` at the end of your `~/.zshrc` to restore it.